# What is the adjoint of the complementary channel?

Tags: quantum-operation, kraus-representation

Given a channel $\phi$ with the set of kraus operators; $(K_1, K_2,...,K_n)$, I know the complementary channel is; $\phi^c(A)=\sum_{i,j}tr(K^*_jK_iA)E_{ij}$
what will be the adjoint of this complementary channel $\phi^{c}(A)^\dagger$?

Answer (score 3):

Let us first suppose more generally that we have a map defined as
$$
\Psi(X) = \sum_k \langle B_k, X \rangle A_k
$$
for all $X$. The adjoint mapping $\Psi^{\ast}$ must satisfy
\begin{multline}
\langle \Psi^{\ast}(Y), X \rangle = \langle Y, \Psi(X) \rangle =  \biggl\langle Y, \sum_k \langle B_k, X\rangle A_k \biggr\rangle \\
= \sum_k \langle B_k,X\rangle \langle Y,A_k\rangle = \biggl\langle\sum_k \langle A_k, Y\rangle B_k , X\biggr\rangle
\end{multline}
for all $X$ and $Y$, and is therefore given by
$$
\Psi^{\ast}(Y) = \sum_k \langle A_k, Y\rangle B_k
$$
for all $Y$.

For the specific case that the question describes, we have
$$
\phi^c(X) = \sum_{i,j} \operatorname{tr}(K_j^{\ast}K_i X)\, E_{i,j} = \sum_{i,j} \langle K_i^{\ast} K_j, X\rangle E_{i,j}
$$
for all $X$, and therefore
$$
(\phi^c)^{\ast}(Y) = \sum_{i,j} \langle E_{i,j}, Y\rangle K_i^{\ast} K_j = \sum_{i,j} Y(i,j)\, K_i^{\ast} K_j
$$
for all $Y$.

Comment: Thank you very much